# Open corner in pentagon

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=cyan] (0,0) circle(3cm);
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} 
        \filldraw (72*\i:3) circle(1pt) node (a\i) {};
         \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a0)--(a1)--(a2)--(a3)--(a4)--(a0)--cycle;
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} \draw[black] (72*\i:3.3) node (b\i) {$A_{\i}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this output:

[image]

Why the corners are not closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gaps are caused by the `inner sep` of a `node` (and if you then draw starting from the node Ti*k*Z will only start the line outside of the node).

I'd suggest you change the order in which you do things: First only place coordinates, then draw the lines, and after that draw the circles (else the lines would be above the circles). This is what the following does:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[color=cyan] (0,0) circle(3cm);
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} \path (72*\i:3) coordinate (a\i);
  \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a0)--(a1)--(a2)--(a3)--(a4)--(a0)--cycle;
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \filldraw (a\i) circle[radius=1pt] (72*\i:3.3) node (b\i) {$A_{\i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]